# Reading the same file has different output in newer readr version

Tags: r, tidyverse, readr

Reading a file doesn't return the same output in the newer R versions.

I have a file with the format:

```
      Symbol                 Location  N_ind_freqs
     A3GALT2      1:33772367-33786699            1
      ABCB10    1:229652329-229694442            1
       ABCD3      1:94883933-94984222            4
        ABL2    1:179068462-179198819            6
```

and used to read using the line:

```
df_out <- read_delim("file.out", delim = " ", trim_ws = TRUE, col_types = "ccd")
```

You could observe the spaces in the first column `Symbol` and needs to be trimmed. This code snippet returns the dataframe as expected (3 columns and 4 rows).

However, the `readr::read_delim` doesn't result in the same output (`df_out`) in the newer versions of the R (R 4.1.0).

What do you suggest as the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is not caused by the new version of R, but by a new version of the `readr` package (assuming you function `read_delim` is from `readr`). They released version 2.0.0 mid July and quite a few details have changed.

If this is really the source of yourr problem, you should be able to return to the old behaviour by using the `with_edition` function.

```
df_out <- with_edition(1, read_delim("file.out", delim = " ", trim_ws = TRUE, col_types = "ccd"))
```